# How to trigger the DropDownMenu on navigating to a page?

Tags: flutter

I want my dropDownButton to show the DropDownmenu for selection as soon as the user navigates to the page(instead of manually having to click the button). How can I achieve this ?

My DropDown button

```
DropdownButton<String>(
    isDense: true,
    isExpanded: true,
    value: _currentlySelected,
    onChanged: (String newValue) {
        setState(() {
            _currentlySelected = newValue;
        });
    },
    items: items.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child:  Text(value),
        );
    }).toList(),
),
```

Comment: I tried to find a solution but I couldn't find a convenient way. Since DropdownButton does not make its handleTap() method (where its generating the overlay with the available items) callable from the outside you would either need a way to "simulate" a click or change the implementation of DropdownButton to make the handleTap() method callable outside of the widget!